# how can I merg 2 xml layout with their java class?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

hi there I have 2 XML layout and 2 java class. I want merg them.

in main.activity.java I call them by this method:

```
switch (position % 4) {
                    case 0:
                        return WebViewGoogle.newInstance();
                    case 1:
                        return ScrollFragment.newInstance();
                }
```

ScrollFragment.java:

```
public class ScrollFragment extends Fragment {

    private ObservableScrollView mScrollView;

    public static ScrollFragment newInstance() {
        return new ScrollFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scroll, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerScrollView(getActivity(), mScrollView, null);
    }
}
```

Also this is WebViewGoogle.java

```
public class WebViewGoogle extends Fragment {

    private ObservableWebView mWebView;

    public static WebViewGoogle newInstance() {
        return new WebViewGoogle();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mWebView = (ObservableWebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webViewPars);

        MaterialViewPagerHelper.preLoadInjectHeader(mWebView);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                MaterialViewPagerHelper.injectHeader(mWebView, true);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");    
        MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerWebView(getActivity(), mWebView, null);
    }
}
```

Now I have 2 xml file with this content:

fragment_scroll.xml:

```
<com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/material_view_pager_placeholder"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cardMarginVertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardMarginVertical"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>
```

and another xml is webview_layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    >

    <com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableWebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webViewPars"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

These 2 layout and their java class work correctly now.

But I want to merge them. why? because I want put webview in a `CardView`

So I merhe 2 xml layouts in these way: (newlayout.xml)

```
<com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/material_view_pager_placeholder"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cardMarginVertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardMarginVertical"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    >

                    <com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableWebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/webViewPars"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>
```

I think it is true but how can I do it for their java class?

step 1:

I create a new java claaa:

newclass.java

step 2

in `main_activity` I call it:

```
case 3: return newclass.newInstance();
```

Now I have 2 ID in newlayout: scrollView and webViewPars...now how can I merge 2 java class ...?

Comment: To merge XML layouts or, to put utilize one XML layout within another, you use the `<include/>` tag, much like you have with your material_view_placeholder.